# fopen('/dev/urandom') on linux vs. mcrypt_create_iv

Tags: php, mcrypt

fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb') could fail for any number of reasons. Perhaps "open_basedir restriction [are] in effect" or maybe the /dev/* permissions don't allow them to be read by fopen().

The thing is...  mcrypt_create_iv uses /dev/urandom:

https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mcrypt/mcrypt.c#L1391

My question is...  if fopen() fails could mcrypt_create_iv() still work?

For the open_basedir restrictions my assumption is yes but what if it's permissions?  Are there situations where fopen() might not have the required permissions to open /dev/urandom but where mcrypt_create_iv could?

Answer (score 1):

Permissions aren't assigned to functions, they're assigned to a process based on its user, group or world membership (or with a finer grain of control if you're using ACLs).

So, if your *process* is running with a certain identity, there is no difference between trying to open the file with either `fopen()` or `mcrypt_create_iv()` (which uses `open()` at the lower levels).

Of course, if the program calling `mcrypt_create_iv()` has elevated permissions (such as a `setuid` program), it may be able to do things that another program may not.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think `open_basedir` restrictions affect C code in PHP modules, only the PHP scripts themselves.  If a PHP script used `chroot()`, or PHP were run as an Apache module in a chroot jail, that would affect both the script and modules like this; the jail would have to have `/dev/urandom`.

While it's possible for the permissions on `/dev/urandom` to be restricted, it seems extremely unlikely (why would anyone do that?).